# How to solve local variable referenced before assignment and return form data in template correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to return the item code and item number entered in the form in the template. This is a very simple application.

views.py

```
def index(request):
 csv_form = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        csv_form = CsvForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if csv_form.is_valid():
            csv_itemcode= csv_form.cleaned_data['item_code']
            csv_itemnumber= csv_form.cleaned_data['item_number']
        else:
            csv_form = CsvForm()
 context = {'csv_itemcode': csv_itemcode, 'csv_itemnumber': csv_itemnumber,'csv_form':csv_form} 
 return render(request,'colorlib-regform-6/submit.html',context)
```

submit.html

```
<html>
<body>
<h4>{{ csv_itemcode }}</h4>
<h4>{{ csv_itemnumber }}</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

I got local variable csv_itemcode referenced before assignment. Any suggestions towards this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what is happening is in your if statement you are creating a variable csv_itemcode for use within the if scope.So try to add inside if statement.
You can do like this

```
    def index(request):
      csv_form = ''
      if request.method == 'POST':
        csv_form = CsvForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if csv_form.is_valid():
            csv_itemcode= csv_form.cleaned_data['item_code']
            csv_itemnumber= csv_form.cleaned_data['item_number']
            context = {'csv_itemcode': csv_itemcode, 'csv_itemnumber': csv_itemnumber}
            return render(request,'colorlib-regform-6/submit.html',context)
        else:
            csv_form = CsvForm()
            context = {'csv_form':csv_form} 
            return render(request,'colorlib-regform-6/submit.html',context)
     else:
         return render(request,'colorlib-regform-6/submit.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You variable `csv_itemcode` is used in your template but it hasn't been assigned any value yet thus in other words it does not exist. In order to get around this you could initialize it with None or some other appropriate default value. Thus a smiliar problem will occur with your another variable `csv_itemnumber`.

In case you dont want to display the variable until it is assigned a value then you may use something like

```
{% if csv_itemcode != None and csv_itemnumber != None %}

<h4>{{ csv_itemcode }}</h4>
<h4>{{ csv_itemnumber }}</h4>


{% else %}
<h4>Some Default Text</h4>

{% endif %}
```

Do remember to initialize your variables to None in order for this to work. You may choose some other appropriate default values then just change the

```
{% if csv_itemcode != None and csv_itemnumber != None %}
```

statement accordingly.

Comment: the template is showing the csv_itemcode and csv_itemnumber which is initialized at first. not the one I want to accept values in this field from form

Comment: Could you post the exact error that you got while running the same ? Surround it with ``` ``` in order to format the error.